# Spring Boot Security JSP tags

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have a Spring Boot webapp and Spring Security configured.
If I login as ADMIN I am not able to see the menu link configured like this:

`<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    <li>
        <a href="references">References
        </a>
    </li>
</sec:authorize>`

Any idea?

Thanks
R.

Comment: have you added taglib  <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %> ?

Comment: Yes I have, I think I need to configure the interceptor url but I don´n know how in spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was the security authorized tag :

'
        DISPLAY CONTENT
'

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to add taglib in your jsp page.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

And see that you have the dependency for it.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    <version>X.X.X</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, I have it implemented . The problem is I want to hide a menu link for role USER